# Can i use placeholder as an index for an array in c++?

Tags: c++, vector, placeholder, c++03

I'll show code block.

```
void function(int n) {}


int arr[10] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
std::vector<int> v;
for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
    v.push_back(i);

std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), boost::bind(&function, arr[_1]))
```

Is there a way to use placeholder as an index for an array in the code above?

I am limited to gcc 4.4.7, so I cannot use C++11 and beyond.

Comment: Do you want to do `arr[v[i]]` or `arr[i]` (they do the same thing in your code)? Could you please spell out the equivalent `for` loop for clarity?

Comment: What do you want to pass to the function, the values in the array? Or the index of the elements? Both? Something else?

Comment: @MaxLanghof
I want arr[v[i]] !!!

Comment: @Someprogrammerd
pass values in the array!

Comment: Maybe should have used different values in the array, because with the array you show, and the initialization of the vector, then for any valid index `i` then `v[i] == i` *and* `arr[i] == i` as well, from which follows that `arr[v[i]] == i`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude
Unfortunately, we are using a compiler that supports gcc c++0x :)

Comment: Lambda would be the solution since C++11. Before, you might create extra function to do the equivalent (`void function2(int* arr, int i) {function(arr[i]);}` and bind this one).

Comment: @Jarod42
Thank you 'Jarod42' It was very helpful

Answer (score 1):

If you insist for using `boost::bind` you can add `getValue` function which takes index and returns a value of array and make binds combination:

```
 int getValue(int* arr, int index)
 {
    return arr[index];
 }


 std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), 
          boost::bind(&function, boost::bind(getValue, arr, boost::placeholders::_1) ));
```

Comment: Is there any other way than to add a function? Thank you.